# How to get Phaser.Animation's parent sprite

Tags: phaser-framework

Currently when we create new `Phaser.Animation` it requires us to supply a parent sprite for it. This parent sprite is kept within the Animation but is private and is not exposed publicly. What is the correct way (no hacky access to private properties) when we have the animation instance to find out its parent sprite?

Example 1:

```
var animation = container.animations.add(animationName, startFrame, endFrame, frameRate);
```

animation.parent or animation.sprite does not exist; we only have access to `animation._parent` which is private :(.

Example 2:

```
this.meteorAnimationSequence = new MultiAnimationsSequence([this.meteorAnimation, this.meteorAnimation,
            this.fallingStarAnimation]);
this.meteorAnimationSequence.onAnimationStart.add(this.onSta‌​rtAnimationHandler, this);
this.meteorAnimationSequence.start();
function onStartAnimationHandler(animation)
{
    switch (animation.name)
    {
        case ANIMATION_FALLING_STAR:
        {
           // Do logic A with animation's sprite.
           break;
        }
        case ANIMATION_METEOR:
        { 
           // Do logic B with animation's sprite.
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on what problem you're trying to solve? Right now you appear to be correct, there's no way to get the sprite the animation was added to outside of how you detailed it. However, you do have the sprite when you add the animation to it (`container` in your example), so perhaps we can suggest an alternative to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi tnx for the reply. Here is the situation when I realized I need the animation's parent sprite. I created a simple generic class for queing animations one after another. This generic class MultiAnimationSequence triger signal on animation start. And I have a generic logic which will be executed based on the animation name.  For example change of the position of the sprite hosting it, and here I hit the problem since I have no reference to it anymore.

Comment: Based upon your second example and your comment, I wonder if you're perhaps trying to do too much with one function? I might recommend taking a look at using `onComplete` within animations (maybe see http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/4400-how-to-start-a-new-animation-b-when-animation-a-finished/) to chain them via Phaser's built-in functionality? Optionally, add a property to the animation that denotes what phase/state the animation is, and your switch statement could check against that?

Comment: I didn't knew there is build in method for chaining but still. Honestly to chaining them with Phaser with something like this :

yourSprite.events.onAnimationComplete(startAnimationB, this);
function startAnimationB() {
  yourSprite.play('animB');
}

It is not better then my solution. It will be hard to chain N different animations, re-order at  and replay the hole sequence and it is not generic solution, like supply the list of animations and they are instantly chained one after another.

Comment: I think exposing the hosting sprite in the Animation class will come handy if you want to do manipulations of the sprite on animation start or end, without this you will have to keep somewhere an external map as reference. Tnx for the help by the way :)